# "which" command is not showing anything on standard output

Tags: command-line

When I run the `which` command it shows nothing.

I ran all these, and none gave output.

```
$ which /tool/
$ which RED*.pdf
$ which anime
$ which -a anime
$ info which    
$ which -a
$ which -a Downloads
$ which Downloads
$ which doc    
$ which media
$ which /media
$ which    

$ su -
# which
# which doc
# logout

$ which --help
Illegal option --
Usage: fusrfbinfwhich [-a] args
$ which info
/usr/bin/info
$ which help
$ which cd
$ info which
$ which -a info
/usr/bin/info
$ which -a
$ which -a list.txt
```

Comment: @Tim I am afraid your edit changed substantially the content of the question.

Comment: @Tim That is much better :-)

Comment: Please [don't post screenshots of your terminal](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Just copy/paste it directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to make it look good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `man which`:

```
NAME
       which - locate a command

SYNOPSIS
       which [-a] filename ...

DESCRIPTION
       which returns the pathnames of the files (or links) which would be executed
       in the current environment, had its arguments been given as commands in a
       strictly POSIX-conformant shell. It does this by searching the PATH for
       executable files matching the names of the  arguments. It does not follow
       symbolic links.
```

I wouldn't expect `which` to give any output - as the `man` page says, you need a filename that is a command.

Try running `which ls`.

It could be you want to know *where* a command is - for that you need whereis.

```
$ whereis ls
ls: /bin/ls /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case `myscript.sh` was working fine buy `which` (nor `whereis`) wasn't returning any output:

```
$ which myscript.sh
$
```

From `which` manual:

> **DESCRIPTION**
> `which`  returns the pathnames of the files (or links) which would be executed in the current environment, had its arguments been given as commands in a strictly POSIX-conformant shell.  **It does this by searching the PATH for executable files matching the names of the arguments.** It does not canonicalize path names.

I fix it changing the `~` (tilde) to `$HOME` on `$PATH`:

```shell
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/myprgms"
```

Now also `whereis -l` show my added folder.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11587382/4970442) for more about the difference between `~` and `$HOME`.

Comment: Guess this means which only returns executables that are in the path

Answer (score 2):

A good start would be:

```
man which

NAME
   which - shows the full path of (shell) commands.
```

None of the examples provided in your screenshot is a command that could return a path. E.g. cd is a build in command.

I don't understand what you are expecting to get with

```
which /tool/
```

etc.

,but it seems which is not the tool to achieve the result you expect.

Answer (score 0):

**There are a few similar commands that have drastically different methods and outputs:**

`/usr/bin/which`  Locate the binary path of an executable.

`$ which ssh
/usr/bin/ssh`

`/usr/bin/whereis` Search standard Linux locations for source, binary, and manuals for the specified name.

`$ whereis ssh
/usr/bin/ssh`

`/usr/bin/find` Search the current or specified path recursively for matching strings.

`(cd /usr/bin && find . ssh)
...
./things_it_checked
...
ssh`

`/usr/bin/grep`  Search text/files/paths for a string.

`(cd /usr/bin && ls * | grep ssh)
ssh
ssh-add
ssh-agent
ssh-keygen
ssh-keyscan`